# How can I turn off "Cursor follows Scrolling" in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

The manual says that I can change it in "pdf-viewer/configure" but I can't find it in "Options"->"Configure TeXstudio"->"Internal pdf viewer."
I asked ChatGPT and it says that there should be "Advanced Editor" in "Configure TeXstudio," but my version (4.5.1) doesn't have that tab in the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In embedded pdf viewer:

[image]

In windowed pdf viewer:

[image]